# export database structure

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

How can ai export database through PhpMyAdmin

but I need to export it as file that I run in PHP , such as [here](http://pastebin.com/kt226kwc).

the reason I need it this way is because I can create stuff faster this way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method varies depending on the version of PHPMyAdmin you're using.

### Older Version

Select the database you want to export and click on the 'Export' tab.

Click 'select all' above the table list, and uncheck the 'Data' field on the right hand side of the page.

Make sure the output format is set to SQL, and uncheck the 'Save as File' field if you just want to copy and paste the output.

Click 'Go'.

### Newer, AJAX Version

Select the database you want to export and click on the 'Export' tab.

Select the 'Custom' option, click 'Select All' above the list of tables that appears.

Select the 'Save as File' option if you want to save the output, otherwise leave it as-is to copy and paste it.

Under 'Format specific options', select the 'Structure' option.

Click 'Go'.

Answer (score 18):

Uncheck the `data` column once you've selected `Custom - display all possible options` :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Click the database you want to export and then go to the 'export' tab. Choose how the export should work with all of the checkboxes and then make sure the 'save as file' box is checked. Also select the file format and compression settings you would like.

Comment: i have done this but i couldn't find the right format as i need , it's export all the sql engine as default , but that's doesn't work for me.

Comment: What part isn't working for you? Is it over-writing tables that already exist? Is it not importing?

Answer (score 1):

Another trick to do it is `copy the database to a new database`.  `Then empty the new database and export that dbase`.  This way there will be no rows in it and it will export only the structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are many format in which you can export a dbase, popular being `CSV, Json:`

In  these you can simply select `Dump some row(s) -> Number of rows: 0 and Row to begin at:0`  If that does not work just try dumping one row and delete it manually.

This will only export the dbase structure and `export 0 rows of data`.

Image Attached.[image]