# Can I create a composite key for a third table from the primary keys of 2 different tables? Does MySQL support it?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have got 3 different tables:

review table-> this has mov_id as the primary key.
users_table -> this has username as the primary key.
review_table -> can I make a composite primary key for this table from movie_id and username?

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqnjJ.png)

[reviews table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAWig.png)

[comments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnlrj.png)

I can't connect these 3 tables and I can't figure out why.

[This is the error I'm getting while creating the comments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APFpY.png)

Comment: Yes of course you can. If you have any error trying to do so please provide it.

Comment: @Nino thanks for the reply. Well this is the error  Im getting in PHPMyadmin... #1005 - Can't create table `movies`.`comments` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: @Nino I'm trying to create a foreign key connection between movies table and comments table

Comment: How did you write your query ? The error seems to indicate that there's a wrong syntax in your foreign key constraint declaration. If you want an example of how to do it check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create composite primary key with foreign keys (primary keys from others tables), you have nothing special to do. Just constrain the foreign keys and declare them as primary.

With the names of tables and columns you provided, here's a query to create the table you want :

```sql
CREATE TABLE review_table (
  movie_id INT,
  username VARCHAR(255),
  -- Change INT and VARCHAR(255) by what you used on the others tables
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, username),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies_table(movie_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users_table(username)
)
```

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table `movies`.`comments` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)
This is the error I'm getting while executing this query

Comment: my database's name is movies, and the tables are review(this is nothing but movies table), users, comments

Comment: Try to adapt that sample with the correct tables and columns names

Comment: I just dropped my table and tried to create it again by this query but it didn't work

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I've checked the columns twice.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see where's your issue. If you can provide your database structure in the answer maybe I can help you more. You can read how to export the database structure here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962143/export-database-structure

Comment: [users table][1]


[reviews table][2]


[comments table][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqnjJ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAWig.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnlrj.png
These are my tables

Comment: and I just want to connect these 3 tables using foreign keys

Comment: it somehow finally worked. thank you so much!!